# Start simple React application - front and back end with transpilation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, babeljs

I am writing a simple React application and I have implemented a simple Express server as server.js. This points to dist/index.html.

**server.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';

const port = 3000;
const app = express();

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './dist/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port);
```

If I try starting this with `node server.js` I get an error as the `import` is ES6. How do I start this server with babel to transpile the `import`?

I also want to start my front-end code as well, and I was doing this with `webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js`. This works OK but does not start up my back-end (server.js).

**webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  }
};
```

As you can see, this uses babel to transpile the back-end and bundle it into the dist directory.
How do I start everything including transpilation and if possible, watching for code changes? I have tried following several tutorials but they don't seem to cover everything I need.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './components/App.jsx';
import User from './components/User.jsx';

ReactDOM.render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
      <Route path="/user" component={User} />
    </div>
   </BrowserRouter>
   ), document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Do you intend to use the node server only to serve the front-end application?

Comment: I want to serve both the front and back end from the same server, but now I think that is not a viable option. I am now running the front-end using webpack-dev-server (8080) and the back-end api using a proxy on a separate port (3001). They seem to be talking OK, but I am not sure what is the 'norm' for a React-Express architecture. I also am not sure how to run my express server with transpilation.

Comment: I don't think there is a _norm_ - whatever works! :) Using a proxy and serving your front end with `webpack-dev-server` is a common practice. From what I know, node is not ideal for serving static content (the front-end) in production and a web server is preferred for that (ex: `nginx`) so using a proxy resembles in a way a production scenario. Glad you sorted things out!

Comment: Thanks for the info, it dawned on me that it didn't have to be served by Express. I made too much of a link between React and Express... but they are completely separate things. So from what I understand now, Express is good for running a node-based API, whilst your static content (including React libraries) can be served from... anywhere else.

Comment: You got it! And working with the projects separately (front-end & back-end) will help keeping things clear and easier to maintain (webpack configs, babelrc, eslint settings ...and the list goes on)

Comment: It is a nice realisation... Thanks for the advice, and I will check out nginx when I'm ready to test out deployment!